# Product discount changes in checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to `OpenCart`. I have mad a small site with `OpenCart`. The reference link is [here](http://gmentr.com/msplocart/index.php?route=common/home). Now you can see when you will go to the product description page there is the product discount section.In that block of when I am entering any one value for example just take `2` which discount price is €135,00. Now I entered 2 in the input box and it is redirected to the checkout page. Now you can see in the checkout page quantity is 2 and price is €135,00 but in total it is showing €270,00.It is actually taking logic as per product price is €135,00 and multiplying with product amount. But here I want the discounted price shown in the product description page with the amount of product will be same the total price in checkout page so here the total will also be €270,00 . So can some one tell me how to put this logic in Opencart?

**Product Description Page**

[image]

**Checkout Page**
[image]

Comment: so you want to change the total price according to the discount ? Here on the product description page below the discount table is a input box for product quantity and its works well as per default setting

Comment: yes..but in discount prices block you can see 2 Rollen is 135,000. and in the checkout page the quantity is same that is 2. But here the total price should be 135,00.Here in product discount page I want to take discount price as quantity not per item. Opencart actually taking the discount price per unit. But I want the discount will be in quantity not in per unit.

Comment: have to need modify your cart controller file for this change

Comment: which file needs to be change do you know?

Comment: ya i think we have to change the controller/checkout/cart.php & controller/module/cart.php ..  in these files hes calculate the total amount we have that modify code

Comment: replace $total to $price in the controller file where he make an array for .tpl file

Comment: in controller or in view file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19920/discussion-between-user1802048-and-user1640432)

Answer (score 0):

The prices are actually showing correctly. What you need to change is in fact the way the product page shows prices. When you enter quantity discounts, you need to give the "per item" value, not the total for `X` amount of products. To change this to show correctly, you'll need to edit all of your prices to per-item prices, then open your /catalog/controller/product/product.php file, find this code

```
$this->tax->calculate($discount['price'],
```

and change it to

```
$this->tax->calculate($discount['price'] * $discount['quantity'],
```